# How to count current level missed_days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, methods, integer

How can we call something like this `<%= habit.current_level.missed_days %>` where we only call the `missed_days` from the `current_level`, instead of all the `missed_days` in a habit (to just give an general idea of what we want).

For example if two boxes are checked, calling `<%= habit.missed_days %>` in the habits index will show `2` and if eight boxes are checked it will show `8`, but the goal here is that even if 8 boxes are checked:

[image]

it will still only say `2` strikes in the index because we are trying to **only count the `missed_days` from the current level.**

[image]

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
    has_many :levels
    serialize :committed, Array
    validates :date_started, presence: true
    before_save :current_level
    acts_as_taggable
    scope :private_submit, -> { where(private_submit: true) }
    scope :public_submit, -> { where(private_submit: false) }

attr_accessor :missed_one, :missed_two, :missed_three

    def save_with_current_level
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.save
    end

    def self.committed_for_today
    today_name = Date::DAYNAMES[Date.today.wday].downcase
    ids = all.select { |h| h.committed.include? today_name }.map(&:id)
    where(id: ids)
  end 

    def current_level
            return 0 unless date_started
            committed_wdays = committed.map { |day| Date::DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize) }
            n_days = ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count { |date| committed_wdays.include? date.wday } - self.missed_days

      case n_days     
          when 0..9
            1
          when 10..24
            2
          when 25..44
            3
          when 45..69
            4
          when 70..99
            5
          else
            "Mastery"
        end
    end
end
```

We have `t.integer  "missed_days",   default: 0` in the levels & habits tables.

Much of `missed_days` logic can be traced to its controller:

```
class DaysMissedController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days + 1
    habit.save!
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days + 1
    level.save!
    head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
  end

  def destroy
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days - 1
    habit.save!
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days - 1
    level.save!
    head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
  end
end
```

The **gist** of it: https://gist.github.com/RallyWithGalli/c66dee6dfb9ab5d338c2

Thank you for your awesomeness!

Comment: Where's the level model? could you add that please? Just want to see the association, well MissedDay would help too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to see exactly what you're trying to do but hopefully this will point you in the right direction:

It looks like you have a `current_level` method on the `Habit` model but at the moment this returns the current level *number* and not the current level *model*.

So maybe rename this method to `current_level_number` and then add a `current_level` method like:

```
def current_level
  levels[current_level_number - 1] # remember array indexes start at 0
end
```

then you should be able to do `habit.current_level.missed_days` to get the missed days for the current level.

Also, be careful with your `current_level` method. It returns a number i.e. 1 to 5 in most cases but then returns a string "Mastery" under specific circumstances. I method that returns different types like this is likely to cause you trouble.

---

A bit more detail: When you've created the habit it looks like you've set it up with 5 levels:

```
def save_with_current_level
  self.levels.build
  self.levels.build
...
```

so these will be `levels[0]`, `levels[1]` through to `levels[4]`

In your `DaysMissedController` you're updating the days missed count on the habit itself and on one of the levels so I am assuming that it's this `days_missed` count for the current level that you want to get hold of.

Your `current_level` method returns a level number between 1 and 5 based on `n_days` so when the user is on level 1 for the habit we want `levels[0]`, for level 2, `levels[1]` and so on.

Comment: Thanks Mikej for your help! I'm confused about your code if you don't mind indulging me for a second. How would subtracting -1 create the ability to only count `missed_days` from the current level? This would mean that the number shown in the index would always be either 0, 1, 2, 3? The number of the index in other words would reflect the checkboxes of the current row that represents the level a user is on. Is that a better explanation? Or maybe I'm completely misunderstanding your answer. In that case, sorry!

Comment: I've just updated the answer with a bit more detail. It could be that I've not fully understood what you're trying to do yet, but take a look and see if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I finally got it with your code. You were right sorry for making this a lot harder than it had to be. I found out that I was adding your code to the wrong index, which is why no matter what I did I wasn't seeing a change :/ One of my stupidest coding moves yet.

Comment: Hey :) glad it makes sense now and is all working :)

Comment: You were right about `"Mastery"` causing an issue. I then changed it to `6`, but now I get this error: `undefined method 'missed_days' for nil:NilClass` for your line in the index whenever a habit hits `6`. Any ideas how to fix it because it's not making sense to me if you're willing to further indulge me.

Comment: Remember, the list of levels on the habit contains 5 entries so if you try to access `levels[5]` when the habit hits 6 then this will return `nil` leading to the error you're seeing. If `n_days` can go above 99 I'd suggest removing the `when 70..99` case and just having the `else` case return 5. i.e. someone stays on level 5 as the maximum level for any number of days 70 or higher.

Comment: Got it! I realized I needed to add a conditional to the index so that when the level is nil the code won't show therefore removing the error :) This way I can keep my level structure and eat it too

Answer (score 0):

This is just an assumption since you didn't mention much of the associations, and I'm not even sure I understand what you want, but if what I am thinking is correct, i would think/assume it would go like this

```
MissedDay.joins(level: {habit: :user})
  .merge(User.where(id: user_id))
  .merge(Habbit.where(id: habbit_id))
  .count
```

Comment: My gist has all the code your heart desires for this question, but specifically the habit and level model has a `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationship with the latter being the only code in that model. Where do I put your code chunk in a new model method, view, or controller?

Comment: well anywhere, maybe the missed_days model, this method calculates the missing days, but it takes the `user_id` and a `habbit_id`