# How to only show previous & current level checkboxes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, checkbox

When a user is on Level 1 how can we only show Level 1 checkboxes? If a user is on Level 2 how can we only show Level 2 & Level 1 checkboxes? Etc...

Right now it shows all 5 levels regardless of current level, which can be confusing for a user:

```
<label id="<%= @habit.id %>" class="habit-id"> Missed: </label>
  <% @habit.levels.each_with_index do |level, index| %>
    <p>
      <label id="<%= level.id %>" class="level-id"> Level <%= index + 1 %>: </label>
      <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 0, {class: "habit-check"} %>
      <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 1, {class: "habit-check"} %>
      <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 2, {class: "habit-check"} %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
```

[image]

**habit.rb**

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
    has_many :levels
    serialize :committed, Array
    validates :date_started, presence: true
    before_save :current_level
    acts_as_taggable
    scope :private_submit, -> { where(private_submit: true) }
    scope :public_submit, -> { where(private_submit: false) }

attr_accessor :missed_one, :missed_two, :missed_three

    def save_with_current_level
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.save
    end

    def self.committed_for_today
    today_name = Date::DAYNAMES[Date.today.wday].downcase
    ids = all.select { |h| h.committed.include? today_name }.map(&:id)
    where(id: ids)
  end 

    def current_level
            return 0 unless date_started
            committed_wdays = committed.map { |day| Date::DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize) }
            n_days = ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count { |date| committed_wdays.include? date.wday } - self.missed_days

      case n_days     
          when 0..9
            1
          when 10..24
            2
          when 25..44
            3
          when 45..69
            4
          when 70..99
            5
          else
            "Mastery"
        end
    end
end
```

**habits_controller**

```
class HabitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_habit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @habits = Habit.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @habits = current_user.habits.order("date_started DESC")
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @habit = current_user.habits.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @habit = current_user.habits.build(habit_params)
    if  @habit.save_with_current_level
        track_activity @habit
        redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully created.'
    else
        @feed_items = []
        render 'pages/home'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @habit.update(habit_params)
      redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @habit.destroy
    redirect_to habits_url
  end

  private
    def set_habit
      @habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @habit = current_user.habits.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to habits_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this habit" if @habit.nil?
    end

  def habit_params
    params.require(:habit).permit(
      :user_id, 
      :trigger,
      :tag_list,
      :current_level,
      :missed_days,
      :target, 
      :reward,
      :comment,
      :private,
      :order,
      :date_started,
      :missed_one, 
      :committed => [],
      levels_attributes: [
      :missed_days])
  end
end
```

Here's the **gist** of it: https://gist.github.com/RallyWithGalli/c66dee6dfb9ab5d338c2

**Thank you** so much for your time! And if you have some spare time here's a similar problem: [How to count current level missed_days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981637/how-to-call-a-table-column-t-integer-on-a-model-method)

Comment: In your `index` action, why are you defining @habit twice in the else?

Comment: Good call @Beartech I fixed that.

Comment: Was that in your code or just in what you posted here? Also, I have to assume that the `index` action is what you are showing in your example, because you don't say if it is. And your logged_in_user before action only happens with create/destroy, but @habits in `index` uses `current_user` in its definition, will that work? And finally you are using the index in the array as the level, but `@habits = current_user.habits.order("date_started DESC")` orders by date; your indexes will ALWAYS be [0,1,2,3,4] so where do you EXPECT the levels to come from? So many questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I'm wrapping my head around your code. Is your html from the `show` action? I'm going on that assumption until you specify otherwise. So @habit gets set in the `set_habit` before_action. Thus:

```
@habit.levels
```

will return an array of the habit's levels. Apparently when that habit is created it creates all five levels? You don't show your `level.rb` model, but it looks like you have a relationship that would be the inverse of the `habit.rb` code. So level belongs_to habit. It looks like you are creating all five here:

```
def save_with_current_level
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.save
 end
```

So either only create a level when it is achieved, or in your loop code in the view skip the level if it hasn't been achieved.

```
<label id="<%= @habit.id %>" class="habit-id"> Missed: </label>
<% @habit.levels.each_with_index do |level, index| %>
  <% if @habit.current_level >= (index + 1) %>
    <p>
      <label id="<%= level.id %>" class="level-id"> Level <%= index + 1 %>: </label>
      <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 0, {class: "habit-check"} %>
      <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 1, {class: "habit-check"} %>
      <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 2, {class: "habit-check"} %>
   </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks @Beartech! Yea it is in the _form sorry, but it also shows in the show action with `<%= render 'form' %>`. When I try your code you have the levels going in the wrong direction, for example, if a habit is at Level 2, with your current code it would show levels 2, 3, 4, 5 when the goal is to only show 1, 2 instead. Is that an easy fix from what you put?

Comment: Well that seems like it just needs a reversal of the logic. I changed <= to >=. That should do it.